# Getting error during pdf encryption using java only through runnable jar, but working with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, encryption

I am getting below error while trying to do digital sign with encryption for PDF file. It is working perfectly when starting from eclipse, but when I export it to a runnable jar file, it is throwing the below error. Any help would be appreciated

ExceptionConverter: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: 1.2.840.113549.3.2 KeyGenerator not available
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.(KeyGenerator.java:169)
at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler.createDERForRecipient(PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler.java:237)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler.getEncodedRecipient(PdfPublicKeySecurityHandler.java:193)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.getEncryptionDictionary(PdfEncryption.java:664)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setEncryption(PdfWriter.java:2159)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.setEncryption(PdfStamper.java:368)
at com.djcorp.signpdf.SignerLogic.signpages(SignerLogic.java:373)

Comment: Check which jre eclipse and the runnable jar are using.  I guess they are different versions.

Comment: I verified. Both seems to be using same Java version

Comment: Which algo are you trying to use and which jre?

Comment: PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, fout, tmpPdfVersion, null, isAppend);
stp.setEncryption(certChain, new int[] { tmpRight }, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

I am getting error in the above line which uses AES algorithm and I am using java version "1.8.0_212"

Comment: And you are not missing any additional libraries in your runnable jar?

Comment: Didn't you have to explicitly set the security policy in the old jres to allow for algorithms like aes?

Comment: It worked now as it is the problem of jar export. I choose "Extract required libraries into generated jar" option. Now I choose "Package required libraries into generated jar" option